# Как составить запрос sql на вставку или обновление записи с проверкой по определенному полю?

Tags: mysql, sql

accounts

| id | email | social | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a@a.com | vk | 12235 |
| 2 | b@b.com | vk | 53466 |
| 3 | a@a.com | fb | 85643 |

Вставить запись если нет email или если есть с таким email и social то обновить number

| email | social | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a@a.com | vk | 25335 |
| c@c.com | fb | 23568 |

Есть пример запроса, но не понял как его правильно описать

```
INSERT INTO table (id, email, social, number) VALUES (..., ...)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... = ...;
```

Возможно подойдет какой то другой sql запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таблица должна иметь следующую структуру:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
    account_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    social VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    number INT,
    UNIQUE (email, social)
);
```

Подробно:

- Рекомендуется имя поля идентификатора-автоинкремента снабжать префиксом имени таблицы. Это позволяет иметь совершенно одноимённые поля при создании связей, а также избегать неоднозначностей в тексте запроса и не разбираться, какой таблице принадлежит безликое `id`. Серверу же всё равно, какая у имени поля длина - только не превышай установленный 64-байтовый предел.
- Уникальный индекс по двум полям запретит вставку уже существующей в какой-то записи пары значений, но не будет реагировать, если значение где-то имеется значение только одного из двух полей. То же и при изменении - не получится изменить значения так, чтобы они совпали с парой значений в другой записи. Если это случится, сгенерируется ошибка дублирования. При вставке на это можно среагировать, и вместо вставки новой записи обновить существующую.

Соответственно запрос будет:

```sql
INSERT INTO account ( email, social, number )
VALUES ( {email}, {social}, {number} )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number = VALUES(number);
```

Подробно:

- Если вставляемой пары значений `(email, social)` в таблице ещё нет - запись будет вставлена с указанными значениями. Поле `id` не указано в списке, и, поскольку оно автоинкрементное, для него автоматически и скрыто будет сгенерировано новое значение. Часть запроса `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` в этом случае будет проигнорирована - ведь дублирования не было.
- Если в таблице уже есть вставляемая пара значений `(email, social)`, будет обнаружено дублирование. И ошибка дублирования будет обработана в `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. В этой секции значение в поле `number` будет изменено на то значение, которое указано в секции `VALUES` (именно это делает использованная функция), а остальные поля не изменятся. Конечно, ничто не запрещает указать там иное значение или выражение - например, если написать `number = number + VALUES(number)`, то указанное в VALUES значение будет прибавлено к существующему.
- Если после применения изменений секции `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` будет обнаружена ошибка дублирования другого уникального индекса или этого, но с другой записью - это приведёт к ошибке исполнения запроса - ведь второго обработчика в запросе нет.

Answer (score 1):

Эту логику лучше всего перенести на сторону сервера, а не делать на стороне БД, так как это не явная логика работы приложения. Бд должна просто хранить и отдавать данные, все остальные манипуляции, связанные с бизнес процессами, должны быть на стороне сервера

Comment: *Бд должна просто хранить и отдавать данные, все остальные манипуляции, связанные с бизнес процессами, должны быть на стороне сервера* Не говорите ерунды. Сервер БД выполнит все те же операции гораздо эффективнее, и затратит на них куда как меньше ресурсов.

Comment: Вы внимательно читаете? Я где-то написал, что БД медленно будет работать и потратит больше ресурсов? Я написал, что с точки зрения коммерческой разработки бизнес логика на стороне БД - это размазывание процессов

Comment: Нет, это нежелание или неумение включить сервер БД в состав средств хранения и обработки данных. Причём в основном со стороны разработчиков языков программирования и фреймворков. Как результат - СУБД не воспринимается составной частью приложения, а отсюда и мнение, что логика размазывается. Я, например, не вижу никакой разницы между встроенной в язык функцией или между методом какого-то фреймворка, и процедурой или триггером SQL-сервера. И то, и другое есть вызываемая конструкция, выполняющая строго определённую функцию, сто раз проверенная и хорошо документированная.

Answer (score 1):

Вы сами дали ответ.
Так как Email уникальный, подразумевается, что он является ключом таблицы

```
INSERT INTO table (id, email, social, number) VALUES ('1','test@test.ru','vk',1222)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE table set number = 2111;
```

либо есть вот такой  [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971680/sql-server-insert-if-not-exists) на SO